# Magento: adding css to a theme

Tags: php, magento

I've picked up the task to modify a magento theme and I am already having huge headaches.

So, I'm simply trying to add a css to page.xml. The css gets included just fine, however, the base URL is off.
My theme is rwd/default.

[image: page.xml]
[image: html output]

What might be happening?

Comment: your url look like `http://127.0.0.1/mrcare-magento`on your browser address bar ?

Comment: @programmer_rkt yes, just like that. I will get the same results for any page within magento realm.

Comment: how do you like to show this url in `link href`?

Comment: @programmer_rkt everything is right up to that point. A little bit further you will find `rwd/default/css` on the top two tags, however, on the one I included, it is `base/default/css`, while it should actually be rwd, just like the other two.

Comment: Check whether you have `main.css` file in the location `skin/frontend/rwd/default/css/main.css` ? You probably do not have that file there. But it exists in `skin/frontend/base/default/css/main.css`. Am I right ?

Comment: @programmer_rkt, well, you're pretty much right! I mistyped sass watch and the file never left scss folder in the first place.
Would please post that as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set your default theme in `rwd/default`. Magento has a call back functionality built in for theme management. That means it will look for a file in `package/theme` directory that you have set through admin. (If you didn't set any custom theme, then the default package theme would be `rwd/default` for `Magento 1.9` and `default/default` for `<magento 1.9` ) If the file isn't found there, it will check for that file  in `base/default` folder.

So in this case, this call back functionality would somewhat work like this.

1. Browser requesting the url of css file to Magento.
2. Magento accepts request. It looks which is the current theme being used.
3. Magento recognizes current theme is `rwd/theme.` Bingo
4. Magento genrates the url based upon theme. It would be `skin/frontend/rwd/default/css/main.css`
5. Magento checks for that file there. Ooops !!! It is not there.
6. Magento thinks then let us check this file in `base/default`. So it generates a url `skin/frontend/base/default/css/main.css` and looks file there.
7. Urekaaa... File does exist. So magento includes this url for that css file
8. If the file is not in there, Magento become "desperate" and will say to us *"Sorry, I couldn't find the requested file anywhere."*(literally). So shows a `no-found` error.

So what do you need to do is, copy your main.css file from `skin/frontend/base/default/css/main.css` to `skin/frontend/rwd/default/css/main.css`. That will do the trick